# why was this question not closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was surfing through U & L site and stumbled upon this question titled: [Recommended reading to better understand Unix/Linux internals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80/recommended-reading-to-better-understand-unix-linux-internals). According to the site's rules, the same question would have got closed if it had been asked these days. I feel it is not fair on new users if they have some questions on reading materials (provided they are not duplicate of some other question) and it gets closed.

**EDIT**

Giles and slm had notified that these are old questions and may be that is the reason they are not closed. So, I will reframe my question as, if I come across such questions, can I vote to close them?

Comment: @syntaxerror, I made the edit. Please let me know if it looks fine.

Comment: Looks fine now. Thanks for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was discussed in a chat session. Questions such as this are just very old and came into existence during the site's beta or very early after the site came out of beta. They should be closed since they're primarily opinion based, just as we do with any new questions that are similar in nature.

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/conversation/closing-reading-questions

Comment: you are a perfectionist as always :)

Comment: Just trying to close the loop 8-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out these questions were asked when the site was in meta stage. However, if someone comes across questions that are not consistent with the site's rules they can flag the question for closing. It would also be better if users are notified in the chat window too.