# The books tag needs a revision

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Per [previous discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2642/41104) and one recent [meta question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/why-was-this-question-not-closed) the [books](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) seems to be the haven for that kind of question. The tag needs a revision of all its questions and we should check whether they are good or not for the site.

Below I will leave a list of questions to review.

Answer (score 3):

- [Recommended reading to better understand Unix/Linux internals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80) [closed per discussion on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/conversation/closing-reading-questions)
- [What is the best book to learn Linux system programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238) also closed.
- [Good introduction to Subversion for inexperienced users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422)  [closed]
- [Mono book recommendations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2094) [closed]
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3294 [closed]
- [Good free intro to Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4248) [closed]
- [Looking for an old classical Unix toolkit textbook](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5723) [open and should remain so, this one is a very specific question since it is asking for one book in particular]
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7517 [closed]
- [good unix troubleshooting book](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10531)  [closed]
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13577  [closed]
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17002 [closed]
- <del>[What unix certifications are available? Are there any self-taught?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23283)</del>  [not about books or learning material]
- [What do all the pictures on the front of the "Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook" represent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26045) [Should be closed as a dupe of the one below]
- [What are all the items on the cover of the "Linux Administration Handbook"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26051)  [open and on topic(ish) I guess. Not a request for learning material in any case]
- [Stuck between these two books?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26428) [closed]
- [What is the best book every Unix or Linux user should read?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34315) [closed]
- [Plan 9 from Bell Labs book](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41272) [closed]
- [Books/Resources which explain TCP/IP kernel implementation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45160) [closed]
- [Book or online article on analysis and tuning Linux system performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48623)  [closed]
- [Recommendation of books to setup and admin a web server in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61050)  [closed]
- [Is the Unix Power Tools book still relevant today?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80631) [closed]
- <del>https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128125</del>  [Deleted]